# Ping log batch won't report the summary

Tags: batch-file, ping

So the batch I'm using prints a ping log to  notepad as such:

```
ECHO is off.
Pinging HOSTDEVICEID.EXAMPLE.local [10.0.0.0] with 32 bytes of data: 
Tue 12/12/2017 11:38:06 Reply from 10.0.0.0: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=124 
Tue 12/12/2017 11:38:06 Reply from 10.0.0.0: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=124 
Tue 12/12/2017 11:38:06 Reply from 10.0.0.0: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=124
```

I'd like it to include the ping summary in the log but I am a simpleton and can't quite figure out why it isn't already...?

The batch is as follows:

```
@echo off
echo  >pinglog.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('ping 10.0.0.0 -n 1 ') do (echo 
  %%A>>pinglog.txt && GOTO Ping)
:Ping
for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping 10.0.0.0 -n 1 ') do (echo %date% 
  %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% %%A>>pinglog.txt && GOTO Ping)
```

Comment: you do a lot of single `ping -n 1` commands. How do you expect to get a summary?

Comment: Fair point. i just couldn't really come up with the right context or language to make it ping endlessly until I stop it...unless I jsut use a -t ?

Comment: yes, `-t` is meant to ping continuous. And after a `Ctrl-C` it does print a summary.

Comment: replacing -n 1 with -t  just prints that Echo is off in the log.

Comment: works fine here. `echo is off` comes from `echo  >pinglog.txt`. Use `echo/>pinglog.txt` to avoid it. Remove the `&& goto ping`, which breaks your loop!